# Upper bound for number of digits of big integer in different base

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I want to create a big integer from string representation and to do that efficiently I need an upper bound on the number of digits in the target base to avoid reallocating memory.

Example:

A `640 bit` number has 640 digits in `base 2`, but only ten digits in `base 2^64`, so I will have to allocate ten `64 bit` integers to hold the result.

The function I am currently using is:

```
int get_num_digits_in_different_base(int n_digits, double src_base, double dst_base){
    return ceil(n_digits*log(src_base)/log(dst_base));
}
```

Where `src_base` is in `{2, ..., 10 + 26}` and `dst_base` is in `{2^8, 2^16, 2^32, 2^64}`.

I am not sure if the result will always be correctly rounded though. `log2` would be easier to reason about, but I read that older versions of Microsoft Visual C++ do not support that function. It could be emulated like `log2(x) = log(x)/log(2)` but now I am back where I started.

GMP probably implements a function to do base conversion, but I may not read the source or else I might get GPL cancer so I can not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine speed is of some concern, or else you could just try the floating point-based estimate and adjust if it turned out to be too small. In that case, one can sacrifice tightness of the estimate for speed.

In the following, let `dst_base` be 2^*w*, `src_base` be *b*, and `n_digits` be *n*.

Let *k(b,w)*=max {*j* | *b^j* < 2^*w*}. This represents the largest power of *b* that is guaranteed to fit within a *w*-wide binary (non-negative) integer. Because of the relatively small number of source and destination bases, these values can be precomputed and looked-up in a table, but mathematically *k(b,w)=*[*w* log 2/log *b*] (where [.] denotes the integer part.)

For a given *n* let *m*=ceil( *n* / *k*(*b,w*) ). Then the maximum number of `dst_base` digits required to hold a number less than *b*^*n* is:

ceil(log (*b^n*-1)/log (2^*w*)) ≤ ceil(log (*b^n*) / log (2^*w*) )
≤ ceil( *m* . log (*b*^*k*(*b*,*w*)) / log (2^*w*) ) ≤ m.

In short, if you precalculate the *k(b,w)* values, you can quickly get an upper bound (which is not tight!) by dividing *n* by *k*, rounding up.

Comment: I presume `src_base` is b instead of n and n is `n_digits` in `src_base`. `m = ceil(n / k(b, w)) = ceil(n / (w log(2) / log(b))) = ceil(n * log(b) / (w log(2))) = ceil(n * log(b) / log(2^w) ) = ceil(n_digits * log(src_base) / log(dst_base))` so this indeed is a derivation of my formula. I am not sure though if this really proves that it is rounded correctly?

Comment: Certainly correct about my mislabelling: I will edit to amend.

The trick is that `k(b,w) = floor ( w log(2) / log(b) )`, rather than exactly `w * log(2)/log(b)`. On one hand, this means you can calculate `k(b,w)` exactly (either by taking the float approximation and adjusting as required, or by doing a search on _j_ in the integer domain for when 2^_w_ - _b_^_j_ becomes negative), and on the other it means that the value of _m_ derived above is an upper bound, rather than being exact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about float point rounding in this case, but it is relatively easy to implement this using only integers, as log2 is a classic bit manipulation pattern and integer division can be easily rounded up. The following code is equivalent to yours, but using integers:

```
// Returns log2(x) rounded up using bit manipulation (not most efficient way)
unsigned int log2(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int y = 0;
    --x;
    while (x) {
        y++;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return y;
}

// Returns ceil(a/b) using integer division
unsigned int roundup(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    return (a + b - 1) / b;
}

unsigned int get_num_digits_in_different_base(unsigned int n_digits, unsigned int src_base, unsigned int log2_dst_base)
{
    return roundup(n_digits * log2(src_base), log2_dst_base);
}
```

Please, note that:

- This function return different results compared to yours! However, in every case I looked, both were still correct (the smaller value was more accurate, but your requirement is just an upper bound).
- The integer version I wrote receives `log2_dst_base` instead of `dst_base` to avoid overflow for `2^64`.
- `log2` can be made more efficient using lookup tables.
- I've used `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Comment: This is a great solution, too. I feel bad now because I am not allowed to accept two answers at once.